# how to read a textbox value excluding commas using jquery

Tags: jquery

My requirement is to read a textbox value with a currency formatted number. 
eg: 3,500

How to read the textbox value excluding comma in the number? Can anyone please help me in doing this using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input').val().replace(',', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the value, split it (by comma), then join it back together

```
$('#box').val().split(',').join();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = Number($("input:text").val().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
```